# Are there any other industries apart from Post and Railways that Terry Pratchett explored in Discworld series?

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld

I enjoyed *Raising Steam* a lot, and while reading *Postal* enjoyed that too. Are there any other industries that Sir Terry Pratchett explored in the Discworld series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Depending on what exactly you think is an "industry", the following might all fit:

1. *Moving Pictures* is about the movie industry.
2. *Soul Music* is about bands and music, and the music industry
3. *The Truth* is about the newspaper world.
4. *Making Money* is about banking (and has the same protagonist as Postal and Raising steam)

Also, *Unseen Academicals* has a minor theme about the fashion industry, but is much more about sports.

In guides to reading order (such as the one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discworld)), there is a track called the "industrial revolution". That excludes *Soul music* (because Death is one of the protagonists, so it is placed in his track), and includes *Monstrous regiment*. The latter does link up with *The Truth*, but is much more about war and the life of soldiers than any industry.

Comment: And of course you could say several of the Watch books chart the evolution of policing, if that counts as an industry.